# Displaying paragraphs in table style without tables

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

Quick question about some CSS. I've had this page that was coded with tables and I would now like to transition it to CSS. The table has pictures and contact info for a list of people, so it was put in a 2x2 table (there are four people). Now there are four paragraphs filled with the information that I need, I just need to lay them out in the correct order. Currently they are all of the same class, would it help to add ids to all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to a `<div class="container">` container, and give the `<p>`-tags the following styles:

```
div.container p {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's perfectly alright if they have the same class. Let's say they have the class `myblock`.

```
.myblock {
    width:50%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
}
.myblock img {
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

Then this code would just put two of those blocks next to each other, two per row.

```
<div class="myblock"> 
        <!-- The paragraph --> 
        <img src="people/photo.jpg"/> 
        Name<br/>
        Position<br/> 
        Tel. 123 12345-314
</div>
```

Comment: works the same as the poster below but I don't want all the paragraphs on that page to have this style.

Comment: If you put a container around them (just those you want to block), then the CSS would not apply to all the `<p>` tags on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
p {
    display: table-cell
}
```

Edit: What is the correct order? Can you post some code or layout examples?